# Solve the EM algorithm of the Gaussian mixture model

Tags: expectation-maximization

Considering a mixture of two normally distributed random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and considering the linear combination of the two:

$$
\begin{gathered}
Y_{1} \sim N\left(\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}^{2}\right) \quad(M 1), \quad Y_{2} \sim N\left(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}^{2}\right) \quad(M 2) \\
Y=\Delta Y_{1}+(1-\Delta) Y_{2}
\end{gathered}
$$

where $$
\Delta \in\{0,1\} \text { with } \operatorname{Pr}(\Delta=1)=\pi
$$

If we denote the normal density function as $\phi_{\theta}(x)$ with $\theta=\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$, the density function of $Y$ is $\pi \phi_{\theta_{1}}(y)+(1-\pi) \phi_{\theta_{2}}(y)$.

Suppose that we don't know what the value $\Delta_{i}$ is hence treat it as a latent variable, we substitute it  with $\gamma_{i}(\boldsymbol{\theta})=E\left(\Delta_{i} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}, \mathbf{y}\right)=\operatorname{Pr}\left(\Delta_{i}=1 \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}, \mathbf{y}\right)$ and try to estimate the parameter using EM algorithm. How should I solve this problem? I am a little bit clueless. I know in the EM algorithm we should first find the expectation of the latent variable, which in this case, is $\Delta$ and then maximize $\Delta$ using a partial derivative. But how do I do with this specific question?

What will be the E step of the log-likelihood look like? And what about the M step?

Comment: Are you doing this problem as a test to see your understanding of the EM algorithm or is this to solve a particular problem? The two gaussian mixture model is a little different than the general GMM because the permutations are more limited (there are only 5 parameters to estimate so you can use a lot of the existing literature on this problem to solve it) if it is to solidify understanding then a walkthrough of the EM alg would be helpful

Comment: @PhysicsKid Hi, this is actually a specific problem I am trying to solve but it seems watching videos on what EM algorithm is and how to solve some of them doesn't really help.

Comment: You don't take the expectation of the latent variable, you take the expectation of the log likelihood function as a function of the latent variable.  If the LL is linear in the latent variable it works out the same either way, but if it isn't, it doesn't, so the distinction is important.   You then maximize the expectation of the log likelihood with respect to the parameters, not maximize $\Delta$.

Comment: This case is solved in many places, incl. [McLachlan & Basford](https://amzn.to/3wRX0wl)